# Bash Command grouping on nested while loops

Tags: linux, bash, jq

How can I use command grouping in order to modify the global variable "data" of the following script?

```
metrics='{"names":["metric1","metric12"]}'

data="{\"metrics\":["

echo "${metrics}" | ./jq -r ".names[]" |
while IFS=$'\t' read -r name; do
  metric=$(curl "https://localhost/..../${name}")
  tagName=$(echo "${metric}" | ./jq -r ".availableTags[0].tag")

  echo "${metric}" | ./jq -r ".availableTags[0].values[]"  |
  while IFS=$'\t' read -r tagValue; do
      metricResult=$(curl "https://localhost/...../${name}?tag=${tagName}:${tagValue}")
      metricName="BAL BLA BLA"
      metricValue=$(echo "${metricResult}" | ./jq ".measurements[0].value")

      metricJson="{\"metric\":\"${metricName}\",\"metricValue\":${metricValue}},"
     
      data="${data}${metricJson}"
  done

done

echo "${data}"
```

As per my understanding each while-loop is executed in a subshell, therefore the global "data" variable will not be modified.
I was thinking to use `command grouping` but so far no luck.

**EDIT**

I tried with the following but it is not working:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r name; do
  echo "######## ${name}"
 
  while IFS=" " read -r tagValue; do
    #.....  
  done <<< $(echo "${metric}" | ./jq -r ".availableTags[0].values[]")

done <<< $(echo "${metrics}" | ./jq -r ".names[]")
```

Now The while-loop is not working, the output of `echo ${name}` is `metric1 metric12`. I tried to use this `IFS=' ' read -r ..` or this  `IFS= read -r ..` but still the variable `name` is not containing a single metric but all of them

Comment: May your solution be here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402750/modify-global-variable-in-while-loop/402751 ?

Comment: In other words, redirect input from `echo "${metrics}" | ./jq -r ".names[]" `.

Comment: This looks sufficiently complicated that I wouldn't write it in bash, but rather in Python, Ruby, Perl or NodeJS. If you have jq and curl, surely you have one of those more suitable scripting languages as well.

Comment: @Roadowl I tried but it seems that this  `while IFS=$'\t'` does not work anymore... I'll continues to find a way to fix it. Maybe you have some suggestions?

Comment: @Thomas unfortunately this is a controlled environment and python is not installed and cannot be installed

Comment: @Fabry The error description "does not work anymore" in your comment is not sufficient. If the solution from the link in Roadowl's comment does not work, I suggest to [edit] your question, **add** the modified code and show the output and/or error message and if necessary explain what's wrong.

Comment: @Bodo I did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
  
metrics='{"names":["metric1","metric12"]}'

data="{\"metrics\":["

while IFS=$'\t' read -r name; do
  metric=$(curl "https://localhost/..../${name}")
  tagName=$(echo "${metric}" | ./jq -r ".availableTags[0].tag")

  while IFS=$'\t' read -r tagValue; do
      metricResult=$(curl "https://localhost/...../${name}?tag=${tagName}:${tagValue}")
      metricName="BAL BLA BLA"
      metricValue=$(echo "${metricResult}" | ./jq ".measurements[0].value")

      metricJson="{\"metric\":\"${metricName}\",\"metricValue\":${metricValue}},"
     
      data="${data}${metricJson}"
  done < <(echo "${metric}" | ./jq -r ".availableTags[0].values[]")

done < <(echo "${metrics}" | ./jq -r ".names[]")

echo "${data}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `<<< $(...)` use: `< <(...)`